# Can Apache Jena be horizontally scaled?

Tags: scalability, jena

We are looking at using Apache Jena (with Fuseki and maybe SPARQLER) for a knowledge management project.

Can Jena - or its triple storage engine - be run on multiple servers to let it horizontally scale?

If it can, please provide a link to an installation guide in your answer (academic papers seem plentiful in this domain, while practical guides seem scarce).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fuseki+TDB doesn't currently (Nov 2016) provide for horizontal scale with update.  There have been reports of systems that have built a horizontally scaling solution. They do this by coordinating the updates from staging server and being a publishing (read-only) to the external clients.

(If you want details and discussion, then the Jena user mailing list is probably more likely to reach such users)